# Why do we say #define Processor creates multiple copies in program?

Tags: c++, constants

I was just reading book **Effective C++,** *Third Edition* there in **item 2: Prefer const, enum and inline to #define**  one of the reason given is while using `#define`, pre-processor creates multiple copies of `#define` in our object code. I really didn't get this why preprocessor will create multiple copies of `#define`? Because all I know is that it just replaces where ever it finds that macro.

Also When I created assembly code for my code, I almost got the same assembly code?

*For Example:*

```
int main()                            
{
   const int MAGICNUM 5;      
   int i=MAGICNUM*1;
   int j=MAGICNUM*2;
   int k=MAGICNUM*3;
   int l=MAGICNUM*4;
   int m=MAGICNUM*5;
}
```

Corresponding Assembly code:

```
0004 C745E805       movl    $5, -24(%rbp)
     000000
000b C745EC05       movl    $5, -20(%rbp)
     000000
0012 C745F00A       movl    $10, -16(%rbp)
     000000
0019 C745F40F       movl    $15, -12(%rbp)
     000000
0020 C745F814       movl    $20, -8(%rbp)
     000000
0027 C745FC19       movl    $25, -4(%rbp)
     000000
```

I got Same same code even while I used #define. Assembly code generated by using assembly.ynh.io.

Comment: It depends on the type. If you `#define` a string, you may get multiple copies.

Comment: Try something less trivial than an integer.

Comment: It says you *could* end up with multiple copies.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a #define to create a named contant of a primitive type like int that's ok because the preprocessor always "know" what a int is, but een in this situation it is a good idea to use a const (or constexpr in c++11) variable so the compiler will figure out the type and further optimise your code. Things are different if you create a class object in a #define because if you use it in another translation unit another object will be constructed.